# javascript Asynchronous: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to trigger 3 functions one after another. When each completes, next starts my code :-

```
getInfo(f1 , f2).then(function() {
    setInfo().then(function(callback) {
        Three();
    });
});
```

i get this error :-

```
>TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

**Update**

```
function setInfo(){  

    alert('done')   

  }
```

Comment: or either getInfo or setInfo (or both!) are not defined in the scope you trying to access it. Try to share a little bit more of code to us to see what is the issue.

Comment: need to know more about `setInfo()`

Comment: What does `getInfo()` return?  What does `setInfo()` return?  Why aren't you returning from within either `then` callback to continue the chain?

Comment: The functions `getInfo` and `setInfo` must return a `Promise`

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) is blocking and doesn't return a Promise.  You can't call `then()` on something that doesn't have a `then()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually chain.

Let's assume your code has an API similar to below.  `getInfo`, `setInfo`, and maybe `Three` are all asynchronous.  They return `Promise`s that resolve to some value.

```
function getInfo(a, b) {
  return Promise.resolve(true);
}

function setInfo() {
  alert("done");
  return Promise.resolve(true);
}

function Three() {
  return Promise.resolve(true);
}
```

You need to actually chain them together so they all wait on one another and propagate up values.

```
const f1 = "foo";
const f2 = "bar";

getInfo(f1, f2)
  .then(() => setInfo())
  .then(cb => Three());
```